# Apex command button render based on queue

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

Hello I have an `apex:commandButton`
with action and if statement for rendering it.

```
rendered="{!IF(theCase.Status == '7', true, false)}
```

I somehow need to add to the rendered a statement, which will only allow it to appear for `Queue` with api names `team_CT` and `team_ESK`.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: can you provide more details. do you have to check if running user is a member of `team_CT` or `team_ESK` queues and only if so display this section ?

Comment: yes exactly, user must be member of one of these queues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, expression `{!IF(theCase.Status == '7', true, false)}` equals to `{!theCase.Status == '7'}`

---

to add some logic to rendering condition, you can use [AND, OR, NOT..](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) logical functions.

---

if you are using custom controller - simply check if current user is a member of mentioned queue and set property `hasAccessBasedOnQueue` to `true`

e.g.

**Controller:**

```
public class with sharing CustController {
    public Boolean hasAccessBasedOnQueue {get; set;}
    .....
    public CustController(){
        hasAccessBasedOnQueue =  isCurrentUserMemberOfRequiredQueues();
    }

    private Boolean isCurrentUserMemberOfRequiredQueues(){
       List<String> allowedQueuesDevNames = new List<String>{
           'team_CT',
           'team_ESK'
       };
       return !([
           select Id
           from GroupMember
           where Group.DeveloperName in :allowedQueuesDevNames
               and Group.Type = 'Queue'
               and UserOrGroupId = :UserInfo.getUserId()
       ]).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**VF page:**

```
....
rendered="{! AND(theCase.Status == '7', hasAccessBasedOnQueue)}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below given you don't have any users with the same names. Below solution doesn't use API name but labels of queue.

```
rendered="{!AND(theCase.Status == '7', OR(theCase.owner.name == 'Queue 1', theCase.owner.name == 'Queue 2')}"
```

**Edit**

For the logged in user to be the member of the queue
you can declare a variable in your controller.

```
public integer count {get; set;}

 count = [select count() from GroupMember where
                Group.Type = 'Queue' AND
                UserOrGroupId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND
                Group.DeveloperName in ('team_CT', 'team_ESK')];
return count;
```

And write the render expression based on this variable.

```
rendered="{! AND(theCase.Status == '7', count > 0)}
```